# Ion.rangeSlider Add / Minus and Tabs issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have implemented Ion.rangeSlider inside Bootstrap Tabs, the slider only appears to be inside the tabs, it's actually placed outside the tab content panel.

- So there are 3 tabs **Starter**, **Value**, **Pro**.
- When each tab is clicked the value of the range slider changes to **85000**, **525000**, **1000000** respectively.
- There is a **+ / -** button which when clicked increases/decreases the slider value by 1000. This +/- button works properly when the range slider button is clicked and dragged to any point.

The problem is this +/- doesn't work properly when any tab button is clicked. To replicate the issue:-

1) Click on Value or Pro button

2) Then click on +/- button which should increase/decrease the value from that point but it doesn't.

Please provide a solution for this. THANKS.

```js
var $keywordSlider = $('#slider-bar'),
    $btnMinus = $('#button-minus'),
    $btnPlus = $('#button-plus'),
    min = 0,
    max = 1200000,
    from = 85000,
    step = 1000;
    
 
$keywordSlider.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    keyboard: true,
    prettify_separator: ",",
    min: min,
    max: max,
    step: step,
    from: from,
    onFinish: function (data) {
        from = data.from;
    }
});

    
$btnMinus.on("click", function () {
    updateRange(-1);
});
    
$btnPlus.on("click", function () {
    updateRange(1);
});
    
var range_instance = $keywordSlider.data("ionRangeSlider");
    
var updateRange = function (direction) {
    from += step * direction;
    if (from < min) {
        from = min;
    } else if (from > max) {
        from = max;
    }
    
    range_instance.update({
        from: from
    });
};
    

$('ul.nav-tabs li#starter-plan a').click(function(data) {
    range_instance.update({
        from: 85000
    });
});

$('ul.nav-tabs li#value-plan a').click(function(data) {
     range_instance.update({
        from: 525000
    });
});

$('ul.nav-tabs li#pro-plan a').click(function(data) {
     range_instance.update({
        from: 1000000
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="membership-plan">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li id="starter-plan" role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab-starter" data-toggle="tab">Starter</a></li>
                <li id="value-plan" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-value" data-toggle="tab">Value</a></li>
                <li id="pro-plan" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-pro" data-toggle="tab">Pro</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <div id="keyword-slider">
                <h2 class="txt-center">Custom</h2>
                
                <h3>Keywords total:</h3>
                
                <input type="text" id="slider-bar" name="example_name" value="" style="width: 64%;" />
                
                
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                
                <button id="button-minus">&minus;</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; <button id="button-plus">&plus;</button>
            </div> <!-- END KEYWORD SLIDER -->
            
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="tab-starter" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <div class="plan-details">
                        <header>
                            <strong class="price">$23</strong>

                            <span class="period">PER MONTH</span>
                        </header>

                        <span class="para base-xs-buffer">
                            <b>Data</b><br />
                            Avg. Monthly Volume<br />
                            Historical Volume<br />
                            Competition Score<br />
                            Recommended Bid ($USD)
                        </span>

                        <span class="para">
                            <b>Support</b><br />
                            Email only
                        </span>

                        
                        <footer>                
                            <button class="btn btn-normal">Sign-up</button>

                            <button class="btn btn-normal">Contact</button>                      
                        </footer>
                    </div> <!-- END PLAN DETAILS -->
                    
                </div> <!-- END TAB STARTER -->
                
                <div id="tab-value" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="plan-details">
                        <header>
                            <strong class="price">$115</strong>

                            <span class="period">PER MONTH</span>
                        </header>

                        <span class="para base-xs-buffer">
                            <b>Data</b><br />
                            Avg. Monthly Volume<br />
                            Historical Volume<br />
                            Competition Score<br />
                            Recommended Bid ($USD)
                        </span>

                        <span class="para">
                            <b>Support</b><br />
                            Email only
                        </span>

                        <footer>                
                            <button class="btn btn-normal">Sign-up</button>

                            <button class="btn btn-normal">Contact</button>                      
                        </footer>
                    </div> <!-- END PLAN DETAILS -->
                </div> <!-- END TAB VALUE -->
                
                <div id="tab-pro" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="plan-details">
                        <header>
                            <strong class="price">$185</strong>

                            <span class="period">PER MONTH</span>
                        </header>

                        <span class="para base-xs-buffer">
                            <b>Data</b><br />
                            Avg. Monthly Volume<br />
                            Historical Volume<br />
                            Competition Score<br />
                            Recommended Bid ($USD)
                        </span>

                        <span class="para">
                            <b>Support</b><br />
                            Email only
                        </span>

                        <footer>                
                            <button class="btn btn-normal">Sign-up</button>

                            <button class="btn btn-normal">Contact</button>                      
                        </footer>
                    </div> <!-- END PLAN DETAILS -->
                </div> <!-- END TAB PRO -->
                
            </div> <!-- END TAB CONTENT -->
        
        </div> <!-- END MEMBERSHIP PLAN -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add from = VALUE to the tab click code to fix the issue.

```
$('ul.nav-tabs li#starter-plan a').click(function(data) {
range_instance.update({
    from: 85000
});
```